# Python webhook API

Tags: python, elasticsearch, flask, webhooks, elk

I am trying to create a python webhook to receive data from my ELastic SIEM (JSON format), when I try it I am getting this errors: (sorry It's my first time using python, so couldn't know what's the problem)

```
 * Serving Flask app "webhook3" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://10.10.13.135:8080/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 235-675-806
{"body": "test"}
10.13.81.254 - - [11/Dec/2020 16:43:02] "POST /webhook HTTP/1.1" 200 -
10.13.81.254 - - [11/Dec/2020 16:43:21] "POST /webhook HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/opt/thehive/webhook3.py", line 20, in api_webhook_messages
    my_info = json.loads(request.data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/json/__init__.py", line 253, in loads
    return _json.loads(s, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 535, in loads
    return cls(encoding=encoding, **kw).decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 370, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode
    return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

The webhook configuration:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-



from flask import json        # To read json data 
from flask import request     # To receive headers
from flask import Flask       # To be able to start the application 

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def api_root():
    return 'Welcome guys'

@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def api_webhook_messages():
    my_info = json.loads(request.data)
    print(json.dumps(my_info))
    return 'Connection sucessful'


if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(port=8080, host='10.10.13.135',debug=True)
```

And here is the watcher that I have configured:

```
POST _watcher/watch/_execute
{
  "watch": {
    "trigger": {
      "schedule": {
        "interval": "1h"
      }
    },
    "input": {
      "search": {
        "request": {
          "indices": "firewall-*",
          "body": {
            "size": 0,
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "filter": {
                  "range": {
                    "@timestamp": {
                      "from": "now-1h",
                      "to": "now"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "aggs": {
              "by_source_ip": {
                "terms": {
                  "size": 100,
                  "field": "source.ip"
                },
                "aggs": {
                  "by_destination_ip": {
                    "terms": {
                      "size": 100,
                      "field": "destination.ip"
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                      "by_port_number": {
                        "terms": {
                          "size": 100,
                          "field": "destination.port",
                          "order": {
                            "_count": "asc"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "condition": {
      "script":
      """

      for (int i=0; i < ctx.payload.aggregations.by_source_ip.buckets.size(); i++)
      {
        for (int j=0; j < ctx.payload.aggregations.by_source_ip.buckets[i].by_destination_ip.buckets.size() ; j++ )
        {
          if (ctx.payload.aggregations.by_source_ip.buckets[i].by_destination_ip.buckets[j].by_port_number.buckets.size() > 15 ) // l'action ne sera exécuté seulement s'il y a un scan de 20 port par @IP source / @IP destination
          {
            return true;
          }
        }
      }

        """
    },
    "transform":
    {
      "script":
      """

     String[] source= new String[5]; // Un vercteur qui contient les addresse IP source des scan
     String[] destination= new String[5]; // Un vercteur qui contient les adresse IP destination qui ont été scanné
     int[] nombre_port= new int[5]; // Un vecteur qui contient le nombre de ports scanné pour  (IP source / IP destination)
     int n=0;
      for (int i=0; i < ctx.payload.aggregations.by_source_ip.buckets.size(); i++)
      {
        for (int j=0; j < ctx.payload.aggregations.by_source_ip.buckets[i].by_destination_ip.buckets.size() ; j++ )
        {
          if (ctx.payload.aggregations.by_source_ip.buckets[i].by_destination_ip.buckets[j].by_port_number.buckets.size() > 15) // Pour entregistrer seulement les addresse IP source/destinations qui ont déclenché l'alarme
          {
            if (n<5) // Pour s'assurer qu'on dépasse pas 5 cases qu'on a alloué
            {
            source[n] = ctx.payload.aggregations.by_source_ip.buckets[i].key;
            destination[n] = ctx.payload.aggregations.by_source_ip.buckets[i].by_destination_ip.buckets[j].key;
            nombre_port[n] = ctx.payload.aggregations.by_source_ip.buckets[i].by_destination_ip.buckets[j].by_port_number.buckets.size();
            n++;
            }
          }
        }
      }
      return [source,destination,nombre_port];
      """
    },
    "actions": {
     "my_webhook": {
       "webhook": {
         "method": "POST",
         "host": "10.10.13.135",
         "path": "/webhook",
         "port": 8080,
         "body": "test"
       }
     }
    }
  }
}
```

Could you please help me to solve this error !
Thanks :)

Comment: The data you are sending is probably not JSON, but you haven't supplied enough information to reproduce any meaningful problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Ken, I have updated my post and added the configuration of the watcher I am using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I just found out that the data send wasn't in a json format and to print I used:

def api_webhook_messages():
data = request.data
print(data)

Thanks for your help